# show a hidden element after user login with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

Iam relatively new to angularjs and jquery mobile.I was asked to do research for my next project on these framework and so Iam trying to achieve certain functionalities.I have created a front page where an element is hidden,this page will be shown initially.Then clicking on login ,the user will be redirected to login page,where he provides username password to log in.Then he will be redirected to the same front page but i want the hidden element to be visible.Can you help me with this.My element is always hidden and I cant figure out what Iam doing wrong.The tag with **hi welcome user** text must be visible after log in

Here's my html front page

```
 <div data-role="page"  id="panel-responsive-page1" data-title="Panel responsive page" data-url="panel-responsive-page1">
 <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                /**some content **/
            <div class="ui-grid-solo" ng-controller="LoginCtrl"  >
                <p ng-hide="userWelcome">Hi welcome User </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div data-role="panel"  id="nav-panel">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#login-form">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

On clicking login,i will be redirected to login page

```
 <div data-role="page" id="login-form">
        <!-- header -->
        <div data-role="header" class="backgroundColorPink">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Form Content -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content">
            <form class="userform">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <label for="name">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true"  ng-model="userDetails.name">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true"  ng-model="userDetails.password">
                <div class="ui-grid-a" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" class="ui-btn backgroundColorPink ">Cancel</a></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b "><a href="#"  class="ui-btn backgroundColorPink" ng-click="userLogin()">Save</a></div>

                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

On clicking save,i will isssue a Ajax call and on successful login i will be redirected to the front page,and my login element must be visible.

Hers my controller

```
angular.module('jQMDemo', [])


function LoginCtrl($scope,$http,$window) {
$scope.userWelcome=true;
$scope.userLogin = function() {



     var data={username: $scope.userDetails.name, password: $scope.userDetails.password, callfrom: "Portal"} ;
         $http.post('url',data).success(function(data,status) {
             alert(data.status);
                    if(data.status=="success"){
                       $window.location.href='#panel-responsive-page1';
                       $scope.userWelcome=false;
                    }

         });

    }
}
```

I might be using the controller wrong or maybe wrong usage of ng-hide..Please help,I cant figure it out

Comment: `<div ng-show="elemnt.show">
   //codes
 </div>`

1- This will show if the elemtn exists in your controller else it will stay hidden
2- You can use this, so when you click on the button if everything is good and the user is logged u create the element and then let the class controller do the work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the functionality using toggleclass
I added this code in the controller:

```
 $(".userWelcome").toggleClass("show");
```

And this in my HTML

```
<div class="ui-grid-solo hide userWelcome backgroundColorPink " >
     <p class="alignMiddle ">Hi welcome {{userDetails.name}} </p>
</div>
```

I was able to get the desired result.If anyone else have any other way to achieve this,Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-show="element.show">
  <!--codes-->  
</div>
```

1. This will show if the element exists in your controller else it
   will stay hidden
2. You can use this, so when you click on the button if everything
   is good and the user is logged u create the element and then let the
   class controller do the work for you

Comment: Can you please tell me how to refer this in the controller.Thank you fro your answer